# Inspect a Method Chain with a Degugger in Node.js

Tags: javascript, debugging, node.js, chaining, soda

I am trying to debug this kind of thing :

```
browser
  .chain
  .session()
  .open('/')
  .type('q', 'Hello World')
  .click('btnG')
  .waitForTextPresent('Hello World')
  .getTitle(function(title){
    assert.ok(~title.indexOf('hello world'), 'Title did not include the query: ' + title);
  })
  .click('link=Advanced search')
  .waitForPageToLoad(2000)
  .assertText('css=#gen-query', 'Hello World')
  .assertAttribute('as_q@value', 'Hello World')
  .end(function(err){
    browser.testComplete(function(){
      console.log('done');
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  });
```

I've managed to hook up a debugger using directly `node debug app.js` or using `node-inspector` and `chrome`. But, when I try to create a breakpoint at `.click('btnG')`, it doesn't work, it only makes a breakpoint at the end of the chain. `node.js` seems to treat the whole chain as a single statement.

How you debug this kind of chaining step by step? How you can inject a REPL in this? Thank You!

Comment: I don't think you can with fluent code like this, can you?

Comment: I don't know either, it sucks if we can't :(

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't do what you're wanting to do here. I can't attest to that, but I'm pretty sure you can't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the tap method in underscore.js

- http://underscorejs.org/#tap

Comment: I've tried `.tap(debugger;)` but I dot `SyntaxError: Unexpected Token Debugger;`

Comment: it would just be `.tap(debugger)` assuming that you have a function in that scope called `debugger` that takes a single object argument, i.e. `function debugger(obj) {}`.

Comment: I've try without the `;` but it doesn't work. :( (same error)

Comment: I wonder if there is a way to insert a REPL in the tap method?

Comment: That might be the case... could you settle for simpler debugging? Just printing the variable?